# I wanna to create guessing game, where user should put a right color in prompt

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, indexof

can you help me with this code.
I wanna to create guessing game, where user should put a right color in prompt.

Computer guesses - a color, and user should give a right answer - which color is correct. I try to create a right code for it but is does not work correctly.
Maybe the problem with variables or with indexOf, or smth else.... 
Thank you in advanced

```
    var target;
    var guess_input;
    var finished = false;
    var colors;  
    var presentOrNot;

    colors = ["aqua", "black", "white"];

    function do_game() {
        var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        target = random_color; 
        alert (target);

        while (!finished) {
            guess_input = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors:\n\n" + colors + "\n\n What color am I thinking of?");
            guesses += 1;
            finished = check_guess ();
        }
    }
    function check_guess () {
        presentOrNot = colors.indexOf(guess_input);
        if (presentOrNot == target) {
            alert ("It is my random color");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert("It isn't my random color");
            return false;
        }
     }
```

Comment: What does _"does not work correctly"_ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf` returns the index (0,1,2..), but the `target` is the actual color (`aqua`, `black`, ..). Try this instead

```
function check_guess () {
    if (guess_input.toLowerCase() === target) {
        alert ("It is my random color");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("It isn't my random color");
        return false;
    }
}
```

alternatively, this should work too

```
function check_guess () {
    presentOrNot = colors.indexOf(guess_input);
    if (presentOrNot === colors.indexOf(target)) {
        alert ("It is my random color");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("It isn't my random color");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I changed `==` to `===` which is [usually what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons) in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The `prompt` command returns a `string` value.

In your `while` loop, where you declare `guess_input`, put all your `prompt` in a `Number()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I edited and corrected your code. Try this

```js
var target;
    var guess_input;
    var finished = false;
    var colors;  
    var presentOrNot;
    var guesses = 0; /*initialized variable*/

    colors = ["aqua", "black", "white"];

    function do_game() {
        var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        target = random_color; 
        alert (target);

        while (!finished) {
            guess_input = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors:\n\n" + colors + "\n\n What color am I thinking of?");
            guesses += 1;
            finished = check_guess ();
            
            if(guesses === 3) {
             break;
            }
        }
        
    }
    function check_guess () {
        presentOrNot = colors.indexOf(guess_input);
        if (colors[presentOrNot] === target) {
            alert ("It is my random color");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert("It isn't my random color");
            return false;
        }
     }   
     //start the game---
     do_game();
```